# How to get CoroutineScope in Interactor / UseCase

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Consider this usecase:

```
class GetPhotosUseCase(
    private val photosRepository: IPhotosRepository,
    private val favoritesRepository: IFavoritesRepository
) : IGetPhotosUseCase {

    override suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo> {
        val photos = photosRepository.getPhotos()
        val favoriteIds = favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds()
        return photos.map {
            it.copy(isFavorite = favoriteIds.contains(it.id))
        }
    }

}

interface IPhotosRepository {

    suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo>

}

interface IFavoritesRepository {

    suspend fun getFavoriteIds(): List<Int>

}
```

I fetch data from 2 different sources and combine them. Right now, this runs consecutively. 
When I want to run `photosRepository.getPhotos()` and `favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds()` in parallel to save execution time, my naive approach would be:

```
override suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo> {
    val photosDeferred = GlobalScope.async { photosRepository.getPhotos() }
    val favoriteIdsDeferred = GlobalScope.async { favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds() }
    return applyFavoritesToPhotos(photosDeferred.await(), favoriteIdsDeferred.await())
}

private fun applyFavoritesToPhotos(photos: List<Photo>, favoriteIds: List<Int>) = photos.map {
    it.copy(isFavorite = favoriteIds.contains(it.id))
}
```

Using the `GlobalScope` is discouraged because the job would not be cancelled when the caller's lifecycle ends.

Since my usecase doesn't know about the caller's lifecycle, which scope should it use? 
Would it be an agreeable solution to pass the scope to the usecase like:

```
   override suspend fun getPhotos(scope: CoroutineScope): List<Photo> {
        val photosDeferred = scope.async { photosRepository.getPhotos() }
        val favoriteIdsDeferred = scope.async { favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds() }
        return applyFavoritesToPhotos(photosDeferred.await(), favoriteIdsDeferred.await())
    }
```

or what would be the ideal solution here? Should the usecase return a `Deferred` and let the caller `await` it?

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not pass the **`scope`** to your **`UseCase`** as you will be breaking **`Clean Architecture`**. Instead simply keep your functions as **`Suspend`**. If you want functions to be **`concurrent`**, simply wrap them in **`async`** block.

Use the **`UseCase`** in your **`ViewModel`** and use the **`ViewModelScope`** to call the **`suspend`** function.

```
override suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo> {
    val photos = async { photosRepository.getPhotos() }
    val favoriteIds = async { favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds() }

    return photos.await().map {
        it.copy(isFavorite = favoriteIds.await().contains(it.id))
    }
}
```

## EDIT

As mentioned **`async`** need a scope, a good solution would be to create a simple **`CoroutineScope`** in the **`UseCase`** whose job would be to scope this single coroutine that will run these two **`async`** tasks concurrently.

```
val customScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

override suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo> {
    customScope.launch {
        val photos = async { photosRepository.getPhotos() }
        val favoriteIds = async { favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds()}
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: async cannot be started without a CoroutineScope (might have been different in earlier versions).

Comment: Edited the answer, please refer.

Answer (score 0):

```
override suspend fun getPhotos(): List<Photo> {
    return coroutineScope {
        val photos = async {photosRepository.getPhotos()}
        val favoriteIds = async {favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds()}
        
        photos.await().map {
            it.copy(isFavorite = favoriteIds.await().contains(it.id))
        }
    }
}
```

no need to reinvent the wheel. details - [coroutines-best-practices](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#create-coroutines-data-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Handling scope outside the `context` of `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` is not a suggested way as proper cleanup when `ViewModel` or `lifecycle` is destroyed will not take place and also considering exceptions that might happen inside the `coroutine`, I think we should handle this case inside `viewModel` with `viewModelScope`

So in `GetPhotosUseCaseImpl.kt` implementation should be

```
class GetPhotosUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(private val repository: PhotoRepository):GetPhotosUseCase{
    override suspend fun getPhotos(): Flow<List<Photo>> {
        return repository.getPhotos()
    }  
}
```

Then Our `PhotoViewModel.kt` should be like

```
class PhotoViewModel : ViewModel(){
    fun getPhotos(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val photosDeferred = async { photosRepository.getPhotos() }
            val favoriteIdsDeferred = async { favoritesRepository.getFavoriteIds() }
           val data =  listOf(photosDeferred,favoriteIdsDeferred).awaitAll()
            _stateFlow.value = data
        }
    }
}
```